# Is it possible to get all the live order or campaign running on my google ad manager using GAM API

Tags: python, google-ads-api, google-ads-script, google-ads-data-hub

I'm trying to get all the orders that are live at the moment is it possible to get them with more details, that if they have applied an audience segment, all details information about that campaign please, is there a way to do it using Python?

I tried to get successfully all the orders but not the current ones, I just want only the live campgaigns